# Categorize z-scores in low, mid, high with equal size

Tags: normal-distribution, z-score

I have a table of z-scores as follows. Scores are based on the "dur" row. I would like to "categorize" those scores in three categories (low, mid, high), indicating how far they are from the mean *while at the same time ensuring* that all three categories have more or less the same number of items.

| token | Hospital | nurse | Colin | Norris | was | imprisoned | for | life | today | for | the | killing | of | four | of | his | patients | . |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| zscore | 0.60 | 0.60 | -0.11 | -0.50 | 1.56 | 1.56 | 1.56 | 1.56 | -0.11 | -0.89 | -0.97 | 0.52 | -0.97 | -1.09 | -1.09 | -0.82 | -0.30 | -1.09 |
| dur | 3063 | 3063 | 1781 | 1078 | 4797 | 4797 | 4797 | 4797 | 1781 | 360 | 218 | 2922 | 219 | 0 | 0 | 484 | 1437 | 0 |

I am faced with some uncertainty as to how I should define the cut-off points for the categories. As said, each category should more or less contain `1/3` of the items to have a fair distribution.

My assumption is that it depends on how normal the distribution is, and that the the problem should therefore include mean and variance, but I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: "more or less" is too vague a recipe to produce helpful concrete suggestions. For example, let high be z-score greater than 0.431, low be lower than -0.431 and medium in between. This is close to exact for a normal and may work quite well with some other distributions,  but could work very poorly with highly skewed or bimodal distributions. There is tension between your goals and so a trade-off is needed. But more deeply, why do you think this will be interesting or useful? Binning data is usually wasteful of information.

Comment: I am with @NickCox that binning data wastes information. In fact, from the standpoint of information theory, binning *literally* destroys information.

Comment: Looking at your data, there is an obvious gap between durations of $484$ and $1078$ which is good for your "third".  Two more gaps are between $1781$ and $2922$ and between $3063$ and $4797$, neither of which are quite as good for your "third" and you need to choose one of those (the former is closer to "third" and the latter is a bigger gap)

Comment: @NickCox and @Dave The reason that I want to bin them like this is mainly for classification reasons as well as finding overlap with other samples. So for instance, For the same sequence of `token`s, I have other data points as well (other dur and zscore values). If I can then classify the duration according to low, med, high for all instances, I can find the overlapping categories. These can then be used in a ML classification problem.

Comment: @Henry The dataset is much larger than this one sample and cannot be manually categorized.

Comment: "I want to bin data because I want to classify" is not convincing to me. If the end goal is a classification, that's a choice, but it really doesn't imply binning of input variables as an early or intermediate step.  If you wanted groups of people according to height and weight, you shouldn't want to go (short, medium, tall) and (light, moderate, heavy) first.  That would be machine learning based on ignoring most of the detail in the data.

Comment: The _input_ variables are not binned. These categories will be used as the output, i.e. the categories to predict. I understand your conservative view (which is not intended as an insult) on how to deal with that, and that categories oversimplify things. In my field, this is common practice, however, so I feel that this should not be a barrier to stop me from trying to find an answer to my question.

Comment: Once you've binned, you've discarded information, which remains my major point and indeed it remains of concern if such is common practice.  I have not been called _conservative_  ever that I can recall, but in this context (only) I love the label if it means trying to use all relevant information in the data. Lastly, I fail I see how any comment here (e.g. by myself or by @Dave) stops or even inhibits anyone so inclined from answering the question directly. Indeed my first comment included a suggestion of one possible definition (which comes with warnings about its limits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of values and want to find the lower third, middle third, and top third. This is exactly what quantiles do.

The bottom third of the points are below quantile $1/3\approx 0.33$. The top third of points are above quantile $2/3\approx0.67$. The middle third of points are between quantiles $1/3$ and $2/3$.

In `R` code, the function is `quantile`. If you call your data `x`, the correct command would be `quantile(x, c(1/3, 2/3))`. Other software packages like Python will have their own variants of this. The documentation for the `R` function explains how the quantiles are calculated, since there might not be a convenient number of distinct points that are easy to split into thirds.

As discussed in the comments, however, such binning is discouraged and literally destroys information. For example, a colleague is $50$ years old and read about the risks of COVID-19 to people in their $50$s.

"But I'm more like a $49$-year-old than a $59$-year old," he protested.

Comment: The principle that identical values must be assigned to the same bin should seem too evident to flag, but I've seen puzzlement when people asked for more bins than there were distinct values in the data. This can bite even with tertiles, as imagined here, as even when you ask for tertiles, ties in the data can rule out equal frequencies.